# HERE Map and labeled marker

Tags: android, dictionary, here-api

I'm working with HERE mobile SDK, and I would know if there is a way to create a labeled marker. I would a marker, with an icon (background) and a text on this marker.

I tried with the `MapLabeledMarker`, but app crashes with a strange message:
*Marc code provided is invalid*

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling the `MapLabeledMarker#setLabelText(String marcCode, String text)` API with an empty or invalid `marcCode` `String`? Marc codes: http://www.loc.gov/marc/languages/language_code.html

The `MapLabeledMarker` supports localization by accepting different text strings for different languages, so you need to indicate the language of the text you are providing.

Comment: Yes, I tried, now it works thanks to your link, but there are two problems. The first one is that label is on top of the icon, and the second one and most blocking is that the marker disappear and appear when I'm zooming in/out, while a MapMarker hasn't this problem.

Comment: You can try using the `setFadingAnimationEnabled(boolean enabled)` or `setVisibleMask(int levelStart, int levelEnd)` APIs to see if they help

Comment: I tried, but no changes. I also tried the resetVisibleMask but same.